# How to trigger some code when a class was inserted into a list

Tags: c#

I have this Item class:

```
 public class Item
    {
        public string Name;
        public Entity ItemOwner;
        public Action<Entity> effect;        

        public Item(string name, Action<Entity> effect)
        {
            Name = name;
            this.effect = effect;
        }

        public void Use()
        {
            effect(ItemOwner);
        }
    }
```

and this Entity Class:

```
public class Entity
    {
        public string Name;
        public float Health;
        public List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();
        public bool CanDie;
        public bool Dead;

        public Entity(string name, float health, bool canDie)
        {
            Name = name;
            Health = health;            
            CanDie = canDie;
        }

        public void UseItem(string name)
        {
            foreach (var item in Items)
            {
                if (item.Name == name)
                {
                    item.Use();
                    Items.Remove(item);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

I want to know is it possible to set 'EntityOwner' to a given entity when that item is placed within the entity's inventory.

what I currently can do is this 'Main Program':

```
     Entity Player = new Entity("Dave", 50, true);            
     Item Potion = new Item("Healing Potion", ItemOwner => ItemOwner.Health += 25);
     Potion.ItemOwner = Player;
     Player.Items.Add(Potion);
     Player.UseItem("Healing Potion");
```

I want this specific piece of code:

```
Potion.ItemOwner = Player;
```

To trigger when the item is placed inside the entity's inventory.

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this could be achieved from within the item class super cleanly.
What you could do is add a function to the `Entity` class something like this :

```cs
public void AddItem(Item item) {

    Items.Add(item);
    item.EntityOwner = this;

}
```

Similarly you'd want a `RemoveItem` function that unsets the `EntityOwner`.

If you do this method you would likely want `Items` to be a `protected` variable so that no other class could add an item to the list  without the `AddItem` function.

The other option is to add a `OnAddedToList` function to the `Item` class and in place of `item.EntityOwner` above you simply call the added to list function on that item. Might be what you want if each item has more unique things to do than just setting the owner.